# iterating on fields/properties of array of class in #

Tags: c#, .net

I have a array of class and I want to iterate on fields/ properties of that class. I have tries using following code, but it returned null

```
foreach (var account in invalidAccount)
{
 var invalidData = from p in typeof(InvalidAccounts).GetProperties()
  where p.GetValue(account).ToString().ToLower().Equals("false")
                                          select p.Name;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking up for LINQ expression in such a way so you get stepwise intermediary results which you could check for debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the properties - use code like

```
 List<PropertyInfo> allProperties = 
    typeof (InvalidAccounts).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    .ToList();
 //Write out all properties to a console as a demo
 allProperties.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

To get all fields - use code like

```
List<FieldInfo> allFields = 
    typeof(InvalidAccounts).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .ToList();
//Write out all fields to a console as a demo
allFields.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

I think you need to modify your original code to specify the relevant binding flags - so your query would like a bit like

```
PropertyInfo myAccount = typeof (InvalidAccounts)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .First(x => x.GetValue(account, null)
                .ToString()
                .Equals("false", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

I'm guessing a bit here - because I'm finding it hard to see what you are trying to achieve (or rather - why).

You need to specify binding flags to indicate how the property exists on the object you are interested in. Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am trying to fetch the name of all the properties for which value is equal to false in a array of class InvalidAccounts.

Comment: Use 'where' instead of 'first' then. The query should still work if you have specified the binding flags correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The above code works fine, but if and only if you have public instance properties on the class. To get fields, you have to use .GetFields, since they're inherently different from properties, and if you want to get anything more than public instance properties/values, you'll need to use one of the overloads that supports [Binding Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Note that contrary flags (such as `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic`) work just fine, and will retrieve all members that fit either of the flags given.